# BQ Self-Join Across Partitions Doubling Cost

Tags: google-bigquery, partition, self-join, cost-management

We recently faced the following "issue" related to a self-join partitioned table, which so far the reason hasn't been revealed...

> Ps. Consider the partitions involved having a slightly different numbers of rows. Let's say, "same size"

```sql
WITH 
partition_one AS 
(
  SELECT 
    -- Why using ONLY `id`, charges the same of using `[id, col_2, col_3, col_4]`
    id
  FROM
    `partition_tbl_a`
  WHERE
    DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "YYYY-MM-01"
)

--- This query basically double the price like it were being executed twice
--- when indeed the partition_one, has only 1 column.
SELECT
  id,
  col_2,
  col_3,
  col_4
FROM
  `partition_tbl_a` AS partition_two
-- Could be any other JOIN TYPE – like INNER, RIGHT or even using EXISTS/IN
LEFT JOIN
  partition_one
ON 
  partition_one.id = partition_two.id
WHERE
  DATE(partition_two._PARTITIONTIME) = "YYYY-MM-02"
```

Simulation

```sql
-- Partitions of "transactions" having very similar sizes
-- 2022-08-01 – 13.76Gb
-- 2022-09-01 – 13.48Gb

WITH AUG AS
(
  -- ========================================================
  -- Total single execution of this query – 557.25 MB
  -- ========================================================
  SELECT
    AUG.hash
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` AS AUG
  WHERE
    block_timestamp_month = "2022-08-01"
)

-- ========================================================
-- Total single execution of this query – 1.42 GB
-- ========================================================
-- SELECT
--   SEP.hash,
--   SEP.size,
--   SEP.virtual_size,
--   SEP.version,
--   SEP.lock_time,
--   SEP.block_hash,
--   SEP.block_number,
--   SEP.output_value
-- FROM
--   `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` AS SEP
-- WHERE
--   block_timestamp_month = "2022-09-01"

-- ========================================================
-- Total join execution – 2.84 GB 
--
-- Q1: Why exactly the double of SEP single query (1.42 GB)
--     if it contains only column (`hash`) from AUG query?
-- 
-- Q2: Why not instead
--     557.25 MB (single AUG) + 1.42 GB (single SEP)?
-- ========================================================
SELECT
  SEP.hash,
  SEP.size,
  SEP.virtual_size,
  SEP.version,
  SEP.lock_time,
  SEP.block_hash,
  SEP.block_number,
  SEP.output_value
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` AS SEP
LEFT JOIN
  AUG
ON SEP.hash = AUG.hash
WHERE
  block_timestamp_month = "2022-09-01" AND
  AUG.hash IS NULL
```

**Q: Why using ONLY `id` in `partition_one`, costs the same amount when using `[id, col_2, col_3, col_4]` during a self-join given the columnar BigQuery charging concept?**

Comment: I had the same  issue and I do not know why, but I guess that BigQuery checks for the columns quered in a table and then for the partitions. It ignores if a column is only needed for a smaller partition range than the rest. Workarounds: Save the `partition_one` to a table and query this table for your finaly query. If you have time you can create a snapshot of the whole table: `CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE Test.large_clone
CLONE Test.large` and then query the original table and for the `left join` the clone table.

Comment: @Samuel thank you. I’ve already tried a similar workaround materialising the first query and worked, however it remains unclear to me the reason for the reported case. I believe Google should have a plausible explanation for it and a proper documentation.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: "charges the same of using" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Debug questions requires a [mre]. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help] PS Please don't put question asking content only in code comments. Ask your question in prose formatted as prose.

Comment: Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean.

Comment: @JeremySavage thank you for your reply. Yes I have, nothing different as expected. Very unclear for me the reason yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behavior many times, where if you use "create temp table" in your bq script, then everything runs pretty fast and actually costs much less than when you use same table used in multiple subqueries with referring different columns.

(If you have same table into multiple subqueries with different number of columns, for the ease of implementation in the backend, bq likely just takes max of all column counts referred and bills for it accordingly. You are correct though that there is no good documentation on these. Query execution plan might help you understand more.
)

Now I see you are doing partition2 into a where condition at the end
like

```
WHERE
  DATE(partition_two._PARTITIONTIME) = "YYYY-MM-02"
```

This will make gbq first execute entire left join and then apply where filter for second partition so you are already loosing on number of billing bytes processed on that side. (Without knowing your source tables, this might be the real culprit for bloated cost.)

(Also one thing that is not clear from your sample is, you have a left join but you do not do any further action on it so you will get entire first table with possibly null values columns from second table as output. )

so you can try to optimize in following 2 ways:

1]
Instead of from what you have in your sample below

```
FROM
  `partition_tbl_a` AS partition_two
... join ... on ... where partition filtering
```

do

```
FROM
  (select id, col2, col3, col4 from `partition_tbl_a` where DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "YYYY-MM-02") AS partition_two
```

This will apply filter first and then join will happen , reducing total bytes processed.

2]

create 2 temp tables like below and work with it. (similar idea as first but separation of data into individual temp tables)

```
BEGIN
create temp table `T1` cluster by id as (
SELECT distinct
    id
  FROM
    `partition_tbl_a`
  WHERE
    DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "YYYY-MM-01"
);


create temp table `T2` cluster by id as (
SELECT distinct
    id, 
    col_2,
    col_3,
    col_4
  FROM
    `partition_tbl_a`
  WHERE
    DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "YYYY-MM-02"

);

SELECT
  T2.id,
  col_2,
  col_3,
  col_4
FROM
  T2 
LEFT JOIN
  T1
ON 
  T1.id = T2.id;
END
```

see if any of these tricks help

Comment: Hey Patrick. I really appreciate your *workaround* answer, however the reason remains unclear to me.

Comment: Correct, if someone from BQ team sees this question, they might be able to answer this better. Without any real documentation from them on billing logic we all are in the same boat.